# Sphinx Quickstart options

Tags: python-sphinx

I am including a documentation feature for some the codes i am developing for my users. i am using sphinx documentation for that purpose.

Sphinx quickstart is a easy way to setup the documentation folders and conf.py.

Is there any way i can use the same quickstart script from another python code and do the setup by passing all the variables needed for quickstart and prepare a documentation setup?

The reason for this is my user will create a project using my scripts and for every project i would like to build a documentation folder and setup using sphinx automatically.

Comment: I have solved this problem myself. All we need to do is create a conf.py that has standard configuration details for sphinx. Create a make.bat file for windows or make.run file for linux and use python to create classic html or Latex report using Sphinx commands

Comment: Quickstart is just a python script. You can use the function `sphinx.quickstart.generate(d, ...)` to do the same thing. `d` is a dictionary of configuration options. Take a look at the code: https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/f1a437a21a64014b13cf99d359207d060746c197/sphinx/quickstart.py?at=default#cl-1264